# I want to get output 2^64 without any extension in C++

Tags: c++, integer

thanks for checking this question.
so i wonder how can i get output 2^64, if i input is 2^64.
in unsigned long long int, it just only reach 2^64-1 == 18446744073709551615
the point is, when input number == 18446744073709551616
the output will be "2^64"
but code that i have is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  unsigned long long int a;
  cin >> a;
  if (a == pow(2,64))
  {
     cout << "2^64";
  }
}
```

so the problem is, if i input : 18446744073709551616
it will no output. how can i make the output "2^64"?

Comment: To get 2^n use `1 << n` (or `1ULL << n` if n is large). But there's no way a 64-bit integer type can represent 2^64. The only solution is using a bigger type

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long long` is 64-bits or larger. That means in some machines, it is going to be just `64-bits`. In this case, you will have overflow problem in your code.

Comment: No bro, i want the if condition is true, so it's cout the text "2^64"

Comment: What do you mean by overflow? sorry i don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Check `ULLONG_MAX` (`#include <climits>`)

> Maximum value for an object of type unsigned long long int    18446744073709551615 (2^64-1) or greater*
>   the actual value depends on the particular system and library implementation, but shall reflect the limits of these types in the target platform.

(From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/ ).

This means your target platform supports 64 bit unsigned long long values. Thus your limit is 2^64-1.

You can try using a big integer library, like [this](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) to work around the limitation.

Answer (score -1):

The largest data type in c++ differs from compiler to compiler...but generally unsigned long long int is of course considered large!!
So to solve ur problem..,better change the if condition to pow(2,64)-1...

Other than that if you really wanna implement that condition in your project, u add a "Do u mean condition..like do u mean 'thenumber+1' ?? "and proceed..;)

Comment: `pow(2, 64)` returns a `double`, therefore `pow(2, 64) - 1` will **not** return what you expected. Try printing out `pow(2, 64) - 1 == pow(2, 64)` and see